# How to check email already exist in multiple table in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

**Controller code**
How to check email already exist in multiple table in codeigniter

```
function rolekey_exists($key) {
  $this->Register_model->mail_exists($key);
}
```

**Model code**

Below shown in the model code i joined two table how to check email already exist before inserting in two different table

```
function mail_exists($key)
{
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('supplier_registration');
$this->db->join('customer_registration', 'supplier_registration.email = customer_registration.email');
$this->db->where('supplier_registration.email',$key);

$query=$this->db->get();
if ($query->num_rows() > 0){
        return true;

          }
   else {

       return false;

       } 
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use OR condition to check email in multiple tables.

```
$this->db->select(*);
$this->db->->from('supplier_registration, customer_registration');
$this->db->where('supplier_registration.email',$key); 
$this->db->or_where('customer_registration.email',$key);
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `TRUE` and `FALSE` as well check in controller

**In Model**

```
function mail_exists($key) 
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('supplier_registration');
    $this->db->join('customer_registration', 'supplier_registration.email = customer_registration.email');
    $this->db->where('supplier_registration.email',$key);

    $query = $this->db->get();
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        # email exist
        return false;

    }
    else {
        # new/fresh email
       return true;

    } 
}
```

**In Controller**

```
function rolekey_exists($key) {
    $result = $this->Register_model->mail_exists($key);

    if ($result == TRUE) {
        echo "Email Exists";
    } else {
        echo "New Email";
    }   

}
```

Comment: didn't get what you meant

Comment: before inserting new email to database table i need to check email exist or not in two different tables

Comment: ya so in my code it can archive, in controller `echo "New Email";` remove this and add insert function